# MySQL select if or count

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I speak a little English. I would like listing topics, if more than 0 post.

```
CREATE TABLE topics ( id );
CREATE TABLE posts ( id, topic_id ); -- posts(topic_id)=topics(id)
```

It's ok:

```
SELECT * FROM topics;
```

I would like only topics if count posts > 0:

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE posts > 0;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics t INNER JOIN posts p
ON t.id = p.topic_id
```

Comment: You don't need the `HAVING` clause. `INNER JOIN` only returns rows with a match in the other table.

Comment: Ahh yes... i thought OP needed > 1.. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count anything. Any topic in the `posts` table must have at least one post. So just get all the topic IDs from there:

```
SELECT DISTINCT topic_id
FROM posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join the `posts` table. The default `inner join` returns only rows where the link to the `posts` table could be established, in other words topics having at least one post.

```
select t.*
from topics
join posts p on t.id = p.topic_id
```